# Looping through a list and failing to get correct items

Tags: python, tcp, udp, file-transfer

I'm attempting to loop through a list starting with a specific index, and ending before the end of the list. I'm checking the element to see if its still none, or got set to the correct number. This is being done to ensure packets over udp got sent, then if any are missing I ask for a re-transmit with a list of missing chunks. The issue I'm having is the list I'm using to populate the missing items is getting filled with items that actually are in the list.

```
if response["type"] == "chunk":
    chunks = response["chunk"]
    tcp_temp_chunks = []
    #tcp_temp_chunks.extend(chunks)
    #constantly check chunklist to see if the chunks ever got recived over udp
    time_started = time.time()
    tcp_temp_chunks = []
    while 1:
        tcp_temp_chunks.clear()
        start_index = response["chunk"][0]
        end_index = response["chunk"][-1]
        for i in range(start_index, end_index):
            chunk = fileupload.chunklist[i]
            if chunk is None:
                tcp_temp_chunks.append(i - start_index)

            if len(tcp_temp_chunks) > 0:
                if int((time.time() - time_started) * 1000) > 900:
                    print(tcp_temp_chunks)
                    retransmit = {"type": "retransmit", "chunk": tcp_temp_chunks}
                    tcp_socket.sendall(json.dumps(retransmit).encode())
                    print("Sent retransmit")
                    print(fileupload.chunklist[:100])
                    tcp_temp_chunks = []  # reset tcp_temp_chunks after sending retransmit
                    time_started = time.time()
                    continue
            else:
                chunk_ack = {"type": "chunkack", "chunk": chunks[-1]}
                print("a23423")
                tcp_socket.sendall(json.dumps(chunk_ack).encode())
                break
```

response["chunk"] is an list of chunks and looks like this {'type': 'chunk', 'chunk': [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136...}

chunklist is a global var that is filled as many Nones as there are chunks going to be sent and on chunk receive, the None gets set to the chunk number.

What I have tried:

- using enumerate `enumerate(fileupload.chunklist[response["chunk"][0]:response["chunk"][-1]])`
- using a while loop to check if theres any missing
- rewriting it multiple times, forgot everything I tried exactly

Comment: Make a [mcve] that we can copy and run for ourselves to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why do you say "packets over udp" but the code has `tcp_temp_chunks` and `tcp_socket`.  Which is it?  TCP is reliable and has built-in retransmission.  Just send the data.